# How to set the Visual Studio Code find widget to 'Use Regular Expression' when it is not and to turn it off when it is using it - from an extension

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, find, widget, vscode-extensions

I am working on a Visual Studio Code extension that opens the find widget, clipboard content is pasted into it to be searched for in the current document. At times the search string is a regular expression, other times it is not. Is it possible to set the find to search using the regular expression when the search string contains one, and to turn off the regular expression when not needed? All I have found is a command to blindly toggle the regular expression usage without knowing what it presently is set to. Here is the code section for my extension - this works, but the user needs to set or unset the regular expression usage:

```
case "GotoCode": {

    // Calc Helper: Goto [i.e.find] this code.
    // We keep the Find Widget open.

    let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if (!editor) { return; }

    vscode.commands.executeCommand("actions.find").then(res => {
        vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.clipboardPasteAction");
    }, err => {
        vscode.window.showErrorMessage(`ERROR: ${err.message}`);
    });
    break;
}
```

Thank You!